# How to get a copy of object from hashmap without modifying its value in the Hashmap

Tags: java

I am using Concurrenthashmap which stores Objects. I want to get that object and modify it without modifying the hashmap. How do I do it?
Following is my code:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String,Employee> dataStorage = new 
ConcurrentHashMap<String,Employee>(10000);
dataStorage.put("Employee1", Employee1);
```

I had added an object of type Employee to the HashMap.
Now when I do a get

```
Employee employee1 = dataStorage.get("Employee1");
```

If I modify `employee1`, the updated object gets stored in the `HashMap`

How do I modify `employee1` without affecting the value stored in `HashMap`?

Comment: whats the type of your hashmap <key,value>? you shall avoid using raw types.

Comment: You need to make a deep copy of your `Employee` object.

Comment: The only way to accomplish this is to make a _deep copy_ of the object, i.e. a completely new object that has the same internal state.  Without knowing the definition of `Employee` we cannot help you specifically.  In general you would use a copy constructor or `clone` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a deep copy of the object `employee` i.e. actually create a new object rather than just passing the memory location of the `employee` object.

To learn more about [deep copy](http://javaconceptoftheday.com/difference-between-shallow-copy-vs-deep-copy-in-java/) read here.

You can do it by using something like this:

```
/**
   * This method makes a "deep clone" of any object it is given.
   */
  public static Object deepClone(Object object) {
    try {
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
      oos.writeObject(object);
      ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
      return ois.readObject();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

For more you can read [here](https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-deep-clone-example-source-code).

Also you can use the `clone()` by implementing Cloneable.

Read here for [clone()](https://www.javatpoint.com/object-cloning) or [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clone-method-in-java-2/).

Comment: Can you let me know why this cannot be achieved by implementing the Cloneable interface alone(like here: https://www.javatpoint.com/object-cloning) and Why this deep cloning is required?

Comment: Don't be so quick to provide a "solution" to an under-specified question.  We have no idea what "deep copy" semantics mean in the OP's context... i.e. exactly how deep does the copy need to be.  You go one level down, and the OP's data structure may go many levels deep.

Comment: @manu It can be done. I gave two alternate approaches. Another easier approach is given by Tim.

Comment: @JimGarrison Got you. I will add more details.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee: Thank you.Implementing Cloneable helped

Comment: @PritamBanerjee: Yes, I marked it before my previous comment itself.Thanks

Comment: @subbaraoc It's the green tick mark just below the score.

Answer (score 0):

Make a deep copy of the `Employee` object.  One possibility here would be to add a copy constructor to your `Employee` class which copies over the fields:

```
class Employee {
    private String name;
    private int ID;
    // other fields...

    public Employee(Employee other) {
        this.name = other.name;
        this.ID = other.ID;
        // ...
    }
}
```

As you correctly observed, if you do some modification to the `Employee` object which you get directly from the hashmap, it will "stick" there.  Over the course of my life using Java, this behavior has usually been what I wanted but hopefully this answer is one workaround for you to consider.

Comment: Don't be so quick to provide a "solution" to an under-specified question. We have no idea what "deep copy" semantics mean in the OP's context... i.e. exactly how deep does the copy need to be. You go one level down, and the OP's data structure may go many levels deep.

Comment: @JimGarrison I would wager that the employee class is not very deep.  A SO answer should be tailored to each question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Employee Employee2 = Employee1.clone();
dataStorage.put("Employee1", Employee2);
```

I hope this will work.

Answer (score -1):

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String,Employee> dataStorage = new 
ConcurrentHashMap<String,Employee>(10000);
dataStorage.put("Employee1", Employee1.clone());

In most of the cases, the shallow copy should work.
```